# Logical Delete on EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework

What is the elegant way of the soft delete on **EntityFramework**? I have already identified a property (database field) as deleted and always use this filter on linq statements.

Like

```
Foo Class  
  int NumberField  
  string Description 
  bool Deleted

contexts.Foos.Where(x=> !x.Deleted);
```

It is not feasible on complex queries.

I just looked these solutions.. 
[Link 1](http://benjaminet.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/handling-logical-delete-with-entity-framework-4/), [Link 2](http://blog.jorgef.net/2010/12/ef-soft-delete.html)

Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this possible with EF via pattern.
If you use a Fascade/repository pattern and access EVERY time via that fascade.

eg
     an implementation of an interface on ALL repository classes might look like this:

```
 class MyRepositoryBase<T>....

    public IQueryable<T> ValidQuerySet  // this is not deleted check  Set

    {  get {  return Context.Set<T>().Where(t => t.deleted != true);
           }
    }
```

You would access exactly as if it was the original DbSet.
EF will combine the conditions.

```
var myQuerySet = MyRespository<T>.ValidQuerySet.Where(t=>t.foo == "bar");
```

Comment: how sould i use this pattern with complex queries? like joining 3 tables?

Comment: If doesnt change that.   Send  the join on this Iqueryable method. EF will combine it.   I use this pattern in our respository base and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly querying your context you might want to consider creating repositories over the context class itself (like found on [this site](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/implementing-repository)). What you'll be able to do then is whenever you're querying for records (such as by using the `Filter<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)` method of the repository you can always do the following:

```
return Context.Set<Foo>().Where<Foo>(x => !x.Deleted).Where<Foo>(predicate).AsQueryable<Foo>();
```

What would be even better is if you were to implement that soft delete in more than one object type and then pull that into an abstract class (call it `SoftDeleteable`, for example), and so then your Filter method signature could be:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : SoftDeletable
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably not going to like my answer, but the "less painful" way I can think of needs lots of Stored Procedures: 1 per each Entity, whereas all you do is if exists UPDATE foo Deleted = True. Mine usually look like this

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Address_UnSet]
    @ID bigint
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsInactive bit

    SELECT @IsInactive = IsInactive
    FROM [Address]
    WHERE AddressID = @ID

    IF (0 = @@ROWCOUNT)
        RETURN -1

    -- implicit else

    IF (1 = @IsInactive)
        RETURN 0

    -- implicit else

    UPDATE [Address]
    SET IsInactive = 1
    WHERE AddressID = @ID

    RETURN @@ROWCOUNT -- should be 1
END
```

Then on each entity map to that SP.

You COULD have 1 single SP, and pass the table name as a param, but since you can't use it directly in T-SQL via dynamic query, you would have to build sub executions (and worry avout SQL injection!!)

```
Exec('SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Global Query Filters (EF Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) and [Entity Framework Interceptors (EF 6+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception) are new features that added on EntityFramework in order to use on this kind of problems.

Answer (score -1):

I find it's very painful to do "soft delete" this way:

1. you have to remember this flag everywhere when you do data access.
   Yes, you can wrap it around some repository patter, but you still
   have it everywhere.
2. Your table is quickly filled with "deleted"
   entries, and make reporting, analysis not efficient.

I will suggest you just put hard "Deleted" entries into different table or databases, it will save you time in long run.